# Query on multiple connections Postgressql / DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

It is common that I need to execute a single query on multiple connections dev, prod, etc. to compare the output.

Normally I just switch connections and copy/paste results so I can compare.

Now I need to do this on over 100+ connections and it will take too much time to do this the same way as I use to.

I searched a lot and it seems it is not possible? I hope I'm wrong?

What I'm looking for is to be able to do something like this

```
select 'boston prod',count(*) from persons  --connection 1 (boston prod)
union all 
select 'boston dev'count(*) from persons  --connection 2  (boston dev)
union all 
select 'new york prod'count(*) from persons  --connection 3  (new york prod)
union all
select 'new york dev'count(*) from persons  --connection 4  (new york dev )
```

To help indicate where the data is from the first column could be the connection name that results came from.

I'm working with Postgres v.10 and DBeaver.

If it's not possible with DBeaver is there some other tool that can do this?
Where I can select more connections and run the query?

**UPDATE**: So with dblink i was able to do this:

```
Select * from 
dblink( 'host=boston_prod user=admin password=***** dbname=r2', 
' select count(*) from persons ') as (Total_Persons integer) 
union all 
Select * from 
dblink( 'host=boston_dev user=admin password=***** dbname=r2', 
' select count(*) from persons ') as (Total_Persons integer)
```

Works fine. Since i have like 100+ connections i need to add i want to be able to reuse this script for other queries.

I was thinking i could build a function with the select and the alias with datatype as parameters like this.

When i could get this to work i only need to make the effort and list all connections once and can have a dynamic query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom.dblink_function(select varchar, alias varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(total_persons integer)
     LANGUAGE sql
     IMMUTABLE
    AS $function$
    Select * from 
        dblink( 'host=boston_prod user=admin password=***** dbname=r2', 
        'dblink_function.select') as (dblink_function.alias) 
        union all 
        Select * from 
        dblink( 'host=boston_dev user=admin password=***** dbname=r2', 
        'dblink_function.select') as (dblink_function.alias) 
$function$
;
```

After that i want to call the function like this:

```
select * from custom.dblink_function('select count(*) from persons','Total_Persons integer')
```

Sadly it doesn't work and it needs some tweeks. Can someone help me and what you think about my idea?

Comment: You could create foreign tables that get the data from each server. Or use the [dblink extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html)

Comment: Select * from dblink(
'host=boston_prod
user=admin
password=*****
dbname=r2',
'
select
count(*)
from persons
') as (Total_Persons integer)
union all 
Select * from dblink(
'host=boston_dev
user=admin
password=*****
dbname=r2',
'
select
count(*)
from persons
') as (Total_Persons integer)

Comment: my problem is that my real select is pretty massive and i have to do a lot of unions i would like to save my select as cte. But im not able to call it inside the dblink

Comment: with cte as (select count(*) from persons) and then Select * from dblink(
'host=boston_prod
user=admin
password=*****
dbname=r2',
'
select
*
cte
') as (Total_Persons integer)

Comment: Don't put code in comments. [edit] your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name okey, it's edited